# Multiple UITableViews, One View, Two Filled, One Blank. What's the issue?

Tags: uitableview, ios7, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have 3 tableViews in one view and for some reason two of them are showing data but one isn't, what's my issue?!!

[image]

[image]

I'm guessing the issue is in the cellForRowAtIndexPath declaration. Attached it is.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!cell)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    if (tableView==_titleTV) {
        NSDictionary *dictionaryTwo = [_titleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        NSArray *arrayTwo = [dictionaryTwo objectForKey:@"data"];
        NSString *cellValueTwo = [arrayTwo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = cellValueTwo;
    }
    if (tableView==_cuisineTV) {
        NSDictionary *dictionary = [_cuisineArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"data"];
        NSString *cellValue = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;

    }
    else {
        int storyIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length]-1];
        cell.textLabel.text=[_favouritesArray objectAtIndex: storyIndex];
    }
    return cell;

}
```

What's the problem??

Thanks,
SebOH.

Answer (score 1):

Try printing out the value of `cellValueTwo` to ensure its not a blank string:

```
NSLog(@"cellValueTwo value: %@",cellValueTwo);
```

Did you check to make sure the number of cells being created for `_titleTV` is correct with what you expect from `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section`?

Comment: That returned the array! Really weird. What do you think the problem may be??

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by "That returned the array". Could you clarify? When you print the cellValueTwo value are you seeing strings?

Comment: cellValueTwo value: Bill,Bruce,Bob,Alex,All,Andrea"